# How to build complex value from three variables?

Tags: excel, function, excel-2013

I have an Excel spreadsheet with over 2000 entries:

```
Field B1: CustomerID as 000012345
Field B2: CustomerID as 0000432

Field C1: CustomerCountry as DE
Field C2: CustomerCountry as IT
```

I need to build codes 13 digits long including **"CustomerCountry" + "CustomerID" without leading 0 + random number** (can be 6 digits, more or less, depends in length of `CustomerID`).

The results should be like this: D1 Code as `DE12345967895` or D2 Code as `IT43274837401`

How to do it with Excel functions?

**UPDATED:**
I tried this one. My big problem is to say that random number should be long enough to get 13 characters in all. Sometimes `CustomerID` is just 3 or 4 digits long, and concatenation of three variables can be just 10 or 9 characters. But codes have to be always 13 characters long.

[image]

Comment: You seem to be removing all the leading zeros, not first 0. Is that correct?

Comment: yes you are right. sorry!

Comment: Can I safely remove all zeros? i.e. are there any zeros following the first non-zero?

Comment: The functions CONCATENATE and RIGHT should get you started, don't hesitate to refine your question if you can't figure it out

Comment: @RagimsRagimovs: It's pretty easy. Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: how did you get the `967895` part of the `D1`?

Comment: @mehow: That's a random nuumber

Comment: @RagimsRagimovs do you have a mechanism in place to guarantee no duplicates?

Comment: mehow combination of customerID and randomnr can be heavely the same.

Comment: it's cool in case its that much localized. I am thinking more generally than specifically to your problem. Sorry

Comment: @OP: please be aware i made a correction to the answer to always ensure 13 characters length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `&` to concatenate strings.

Use `VALUE(CustomerID)` to trim the leading zeroes from the ID

Use `RAND()` to add a random number between 0 and 1 or `RANDBETWEEN(x,y)` to create one between x and y.

Combine the above and there you are!

If you always want 13 digits you can use `LEFT(INT(RAND()*10^13);(13-LEN(CustomerCountry)-LEN(VALUE(CustomerID))))` for the random number to ALWAYS be the right length.

total formula

```
= CustomerCountry 
  & VALUE(CustomerID) 
  & LEFT(INT(RAND()*10^13);(13-LEN(CustomerCountry)-LEN(VALUE(CustomerID))))
```

Comment: I'd be careful about the random numbers part as it doesn't guarantee no duplicates.

Comment: Is was not said it should avoid duplicates, so I dont consider that a requirement

Comment: @mehow I don't see that as being a problem since you'd hope the non-zero part of the customer ID is unique. But yes, you should clarify that. And +1 for exploiting VALUE.

Comment: I rather consider real life scenarios and prevent errors etc. The proper solution would check for duplicates. If I were here a year from now looking for a solution I'd be happy someone mentioned the  possibility of getting duplicates.

Comment: There was an error with the random number generator i had, it could give results > 0,1 therefore missing on or more characters in your total string. With the formula above this problem is solved.  Please be aware the formula is localized to use `;` as parameter separator.

Comment: you have to translate the new formula for it to be correct, so take the `LEFT` as well. Be aware that part becomes a bit different then.

Answer (score 2):

`=C1 & TEXT(B1,"0") & RIGHT(TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(0,99999999999),"00000000000"),11 - LEN(TEXT(B1,"0")))`

that should do it

Comment: This will not remove leading zeroes, and also not enforce a total length of 13 characters

Comment: hmm good point... it actually removes the first char.. whether it's a zero of not... lack of proper test data on my part :)

Comment: I like the TEXT() formulas you used, very clean.

Comment: Your formula will give an unexpected result if the number of characters in the country increases. @K_B's formula handles that scenario well :) But anyways good try :)

Comment: it also has the cool effect of changing the number everytime a calc is evaluated ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand what is where and OP has accepted answer so have not bothered testing:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(C1,2)&VALUE(MID(B1,15,13))&RANDBETWEEN(10^9,10^10),13)
```

(but I might revert to this if no one else picks the flaws in it first!)